# Laravel project + media server both for live and vod streaming deployed on Docker

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, docker, video, video-streaming

After many hours of research and nothing relevant coming up I decided to ask.

I am pretty new to the concept of video streaming, so please forgive me if my questions may seem elementary.

I am building a project that needs to include media streaming functionality. It should has the following options:

1. **VOD** - user uploads a file to the server, that needs to be transcoded to few MP4 files of different resolutions. For transcoding I am trying the approach using CloudTranscode (https://github.com/bfansports/CloudTranscode) deployed as a Docker image. The server should supply stream to the player with certain buffer size, so when the playback is paused we buffer for instance +5 seconds and that's it. Adaptive bitrate would be nice, however I'm not sure how this works with different players (I was thinking about using Video.JS due to high customization option, plus it's free).
2. **Live video capturing** - user visits a certain page that captures video from the webcam and sends the stream to the server for further stream distribution to clients. For most browsers WebRTC could be a good option, but iOS devices probably won't work with it, so any suggestions here would be much appreciated
3. **Live video streaming** - users visit a certain page where they can watch the stream captured from the user mentioned in point 2. Here the stream may be watched by one or many users (may be as well 1 or 10,000 users)

Cutting to the chase my questions follow:

1. **What would be the best media server software that I can use for that purpose**, having on mind high scalability (deployed as Docker container on AWS EC2), and possible huge load of both streaming and watching users, as well as multi-device/platform/browser support?
2. **What would be the best media player for webpage** that (again) would be cross-browser/platform/device, keeping in mind good integration with media server itself for purpose of adaptive resolution streaming? Also it would be nice if the player has broad customization options in matter of appearence (for instance thumbnail display when hovering the timeline).
3. **Do you know any better solution for video transcoding than mentioned CloudTranscode**, having on mind Docker setup, and some easy to use API (here some on-the-fly transcoding would be nice, so the worker wouldn't need to wait for the whole file to be uploaded)?
4. **What happens if I use autoscalling functionality on EC2 instance, and more instances of the media server are being automatically started?** Let's say we have instance 1 (I1) and instance 2 (I2). Some user started broadcasting on I1, and 1000 users are watching the stream which is the server instance's limit because it's running out of resources. Next, another couple of users are trying to view the stream, so they are being connected to I2 by AWS load balancer - how does that work with live stream? Sorry, but I am total newbie to the concept, so again - forgive me for elementary questions.

So far a was able to find a few media servers that may be relevant to my needs including:

- Wowza Media Server (paid)
- Red5 media server (free)
- Kurento Media Server (free)

My application is written in **Laravel**, ergo I need some **PHP** integration with the media server.

Obviously free solutions are the most welcome, however I do not mind to pay as long as paid solution covers my needs.

Any input here will be much appreaciated - even partial solutions / suggestions. I'm kinda stuck here, so any suggestions that can bring me closer to the solution are very welcome!

Best regards

Comment: it looks like a porn website. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

If anyone needs such information I ended up using **Nginx Plus** media server functionalities. It's capable of serving both live and VOD streams, it has out-of-the-box load balancer to switch traffic over multiple container instances and many more great features. Plus they have images to deploy directly from AWS Marketplace, and the license is paid hourly when the EC2 instance is running. Ofcourse there is free version as well, but I am really satisfied with Nginx Plus support.

Capturing live stream from user I've done using **getUserMedia()** in JS. Still having minor glitches, but I will get it to work (problems are related with WebM chunks that MediaRecorder API spits out, but I'm almost done here using some Python piece of code modifying each chunk on server side).

If anyone needs help I will be happy to help.

Comment: Hey! Very nice bro, thanks for writing this question and answer. I currently have a similar project. I was wondering if you can solve this question for me: Conceptually, if I am also using Laravel, how can I connect to the user's webcams (with the proper permissions) from the web browser? And, in your solution, would you mind telling what is the current cost of using AWS for this purpose? In my project is p2p only, both voice and video. Hope you can answer, best regards.